# как в редакторе nano выделить нужные строки?

Tags: linux, терминал

как техничнее в nano выделить в буфер обмена большой массив, все строки, находящиеся начиная с одной строки (пусть будет первая для простоты), заканчивая выбранной?
спасибо

Comment: первый вопрос не имеет прямого отношения к программе nano, а вот второй вопрос имеет смысл задать отдельно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вопрос отредактировали - теперь не дубликат

Comment: я делаю `ctrl`+`k` много раз вырезая блок до выбранной строки, потом нажимаю `ctrl`+`u` и все возвращается на своё место. потом мотаем до места вставки и опять `ctrl`+`u`

Comment: @eri, зато ответ теперь стал «совсем не в тему». я даже не знаю как правильно поступить: пусть лучше модераторы решают.

Answer (score 0):

Там есть справка. Вызывается Ctrl-G.
M-/Последняя строка - Alt-/.
По второму вопросу. Можно сделать метку Ctrl-^ и перейти наверх Alt-\